# Basic authentication Rest call to get json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, basic-authentication

In a static html page i am trying to make a REST GET call to get json data.
I have a URL i can hit in a browser with account + secret in the URL and get the json data in the browser. I cant give you the correct URL but this is what its like:

```
http://123456:ABCDEFGHIJKLM@media.fakename.com/Media/service/id/323847.json
```

I have tried numerous examples on stackoverflow without success!
Here is what i have tried and i get back Error:error

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

function getRest(){

 $.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'http://media.fakename.com/Media/service/id/323847.json',
  dataType: 'json',

  beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', basicOath('123456', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLM'));
  },
  success: function () {
   var myvar = data;
   $(".text").html(myvar);
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, status) {
   $(".text").html("Error: " + status);
  }
 });
}

function basicOath(account, secret) {
 var tok = account + ':' + secret;
 var hash = btoa(tok);
 return 'Basic ' + hash;
}

</script>
```

and

```
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="get rest" onclick="getRest();" />
<div class="text">abc <br />'
```

I was able to try the jquery example to make a rest call to get back images. It works perfectly. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/ 
so i know i can make rest calls.

What am i doing wrong? Thanks for your help as i have treid all the examples on stack and the web. I hit a brick wall.

Comment: In your browsers network console, what response code is the request getting?  Side note, your success method does not have 'data' as an input parameter and yet you are trying to use it.  It will be undefined like that.  Though what you are doing with it seems odd.  You are taking data and sticking it on the page, but your `dataType` as json says you expect the response to be json (and will error if it is not).  Is this accurate?  Are you wanting to put raw json on the page?

Comment: Raw data will go into an array. I just was putting it on the page for testing purposes. I am getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) and  Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

Comment: So some where you have a syntax error, and you are making a CORS request that is being blocked.

Comment: Even if i fix the syntax error i still cant do it?

Comment: The syntax error was in jquery example script. I added a CORS plugin and tthat error is gone. However, i am seeing Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401

Answer (score 0):

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
},
```